# What IoT services are available for free that does not have message rate limit?

Tags: esp8266, mosquitto, android

let say my other device publishes messages every 10ms (trying to show a real time graph in mobile app) sending at slower rate i.e every 1s instead of 10ms would result to wrong output.

Are there any other free services where in I can pub/sub messages just like in Ably and PubNub? Both supports Xamarin and ESP8266 (by support I mean, i can easily integrate it, was able to use both/tested), I'm merely sending values such as "140" "300" "200" etc. 1 by 1

Using this service because the ESP and the mobile app are in different locations (far locations)

In Ably it has a message rate limit of 35 messages/second, in PubNub there is no specific limit, however it does not have a guarantee on message ordering.

Can I use mosquitto for this? or are there any workaround for this?

Comment: Given that most mobile devices have screen refresh rates less than 60fps, updating the graph at 100fps is not going to be noticeable to the user.

Comment: send 4 values in one message every 40ms

Comment: Hmm I tried doing 10 messages, like 10-100-104 etc.. Having a delimiter of "-" However doing so I think causes another mistake? Like the time it takes to process/build the string? I'm not sure entirely though. I'm doing this for ECG monitoring using ad8232

Comment: So printing in delay(1) vs delay(10) vs delay(100) will show differebt results, that's why I need an alternative preferably without message limit, this will not be used for production... More on testing